# Spring hibernate template class

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am reading about HibernateTemplate class in Spring3.

Here i saw two methods update and saveOrUpdate , i read it from the documentation such as

- update

Update the given persistent instance, associating it with the current Hibernate Session.

Here what is meaning of "associating it with the current Hibernate Session"?

- saveOrUpdate

Save or update the given persistent instance, according to its id (matching the configured "unsaved-value"?). Associates the instance with the current Hibernate Session.

Here what is meaning of "according to its id (matching the configured "unsaved-value"?). Associates the instance with the current Hibernate Session"  ?

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple - If the object with the same ID exists in the DB , it updates it else if the ID (primary key) is null, it saves it as a new value - Hence saveOrUpdate - depending on whether it's a value existing in DB or a new value.

The ID match happens by matching your pojo ID in the hbm under the  tag with the column specified .

saveOrUpdate() does the following:

```
if the object is already persistent in this session, do nothing

if another object associated with the session has the same identifier, throw an exception

if the object has no identifier property, save() it

if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it

if the object is versioned by a <version> or <timestamp>, and the version property value is the same value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it

otherwise update() the object
```

From [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-saveorupdate)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Here what is meaning of "associating it with the current Hibernate Session"?

Following retrievals of that entity through this `Session` will give you the updated entity. Other `Session`s won't see the update until the `Session` is flushed.

> Here what is meaning of "according to its id (matching the configured "unsaved-value"?).

If the entity has an id, it's treated by `saveOrUpdate` as an existing entity (in the DB). Otherwise it's a new one. "unsaved-value" is the value that Hibernate will put in the id upon `saveOrUpdate` of a new entity. You can configure this to be, for example, negative value. This way, you also can determine, in following retrievals of this entity from the `Session`, whether it's a new entity not yet saved in the DB, or an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

> Here what is meaning of "associating it with the current Hibernate
>   Session"?

Mean that your entity(transient or detached) will get saved and associate with the session(attached/persisted), so from then onwards session will track any changes made for that entity and reduce the number DML statements that needs to be executed at the end.

> Here what is meaning of "according to its id (matching the configured
>   "unsaved-value"?). Associates the instance with the current Hibernate
>   Session" ?

If the entity ID attribute has value then that gets updated and attaches to the session for further tracking of changes by session else will insert that entity into DB as new record and will associate to the session.

Please go through entity [instance states](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/architecture.html#architecture-states) of hibernate entities